# How to find difference between rows in a pandas multiIndex, by level 1

Tags: pandas

Suppose we have a DataFrame like this, only with many, many more index A values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,1,2],
              [1,1,2,2],
              [2,2,1,0],
              [1,2,1,2],
              [2,1,1,2]    ], columns=['A','B','c1','c2'])
df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()

## result
     c1  c2
A B        
1 1   2   2
  2   2   4
2 1   1   2
  2   1   0
```

How can I get a data frame that consists of the difference between rows, by the second level of the index, level B?
The output here would be

```
A    c1  c2
1     0  -2
2     0   2
```

**Note** In my particular use case, I have a lot of column A values, so I can write out the value for A explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Check `diff`  and `dropna`

```
g = df.groupby(['A','B'])[['c1','c2']].sum()
g = g.groupby(level=0).diff().dropna()
g
Out[25]: 
      c1   c2
A B          
1 2  0.0  2.0
2 2  0.0 -2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the first grouping to `result` variable:

```
  result = df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()
```

You could use a [pipe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.pipe.html) operation with [nth](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
result.groupby('A').pipe(lambda df: df.nth(0) - df.nth(-1))

   c1  c2
A        
1   0  -2
2   0   2
```

A simpler option, in my opinion, would be to use [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) combined with numpy's [ufunc reduce](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html), as this covers scenarios where you have more than two rows:

```
result.groupby('A').agg(np.subtract.reduce)

   c1  c2
A        
1   0  -2
2   0   2
```